# React: Object."value name" is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, object, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fill an object and then show it in the render of my application in React:
I am filling it in the following way:

```
  var query = firebase.database().ref("salas").orderByKey();
        query.once("value")
          .then(function(snapshot) {
          snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var key = childSnapshot.key;
            var prueba = childSnapshot.val();
            prueba.key = key;
            var ref = firebase.database().ref("salas/" + prueba.key);
            ref.once("value")
              .then(function(snapshot) {
                var b = snapshot.child("Usuarios").numChildren();
                prueba.unidos = b;
              });
            sala_prueba.push(prueba);

        });
      this.setState({
        salas : sala_prueba
      });
      }.bind(this));
```

And I render it like that:

render() {

```
const ArraySalas = this.state.salas.map((datos,index) =>{
  console.log(datos);
  console.log(datos.unidos);

   return(
     <div className="col-sm-4" key={index}>
         <div className="card text-center" >
          <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title"> {datos.nombre} </h5>
            <p className="card-text">Tamaño sala {datos.tamaño}</p>
            <p className="card-text">Usuarios unidos {datos.unidos}</p>
            <button className="btn btn-primary" id={datos.key} onClick={this.Unirse.bind()}> Unirse </button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   )
});

    return (
      <div className="App">
          <Alert/>
            <nav className="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark justify-content-between">
            <a className="navbar-brand logo">Juego</a>
            <form className="form-inline">
              {this.RenderBoton()}
            </form>
            </nav>
            <container-fluid>
              <div className="col-sm-12 mt-2">
                <div className="row">
                  {ArraySalas}
                </div>
              </div>
            </container-fluid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The console.log of "datos" show the object and "datos.unidos" show Undefined, but why?

[image]

Comment: What shows if you console.log(datos.key) ?

Avoid use special chars as Object key

Comment: Does Firebase lazy load these objects, so the array of objects comes back first, and then later they get populated with data perhaps?

Comment: console.log(datos.key) shows : 001 or 002. I delete "Ñ" using "n". I don't  know why do this. 
The another data: Usuarios,nombre,nro it shows!! But only unidos not show

Comment: It's a problem with a Lazy load in firebase!